# Ctrl - Alt - I investing color instead of making new code chunk

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm used to using Ctrl- Alt - I to create new code chunks in R Markdown. Well I don't know what I did, but now that combo of keys inverts the colors on my screen instead of creating a new code chunk. Suggestions on how to change it?

Comment: Do you have another keyboard app running, such as AutoHotKey? If you are certain you do not, then perhaps (1) update and/or reinstall RStudio; (2) run anti-virus, anti-malware, and perhaps other tools to ensure that somebody else did not install a new shortcut tool without your knowledge/approval.

Comment: Do you accidentally have the windows magnifier tool open? I see in other posts that when that is active, `Ctrl-Alt-I` can trigger "invert colors".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That keyboard shortcut is enabled when you enable Windows Magnifier.

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/11542/windows-use-magnifier-to-make-things-easier-to-see

To confirm that it is enabled:

- open Settings (`Win-x`, `n` for Settings)
- select *Ease of Access*
- left side, select *Magnifier*
- notice if you have "Turn on Magnifier" enabled

(You can disable it here, but keep reading for more context.)

On that screen, you can see that default hotkeys include:

- `Win +` (windows key and "plus" key) for enabling
- `Win Esc` to turn off magnifier

So perhaps it should be possible to disable globally with `Win Esc` and then regain control of `Ctrl-Alt-I` in RStudio (and/or elsewhere).